# Prevent Mac from shutting down while running script

Tags: command-line, terminal

I have sometimes been running scripts overnight, only to come back in the morning to find that the mac had shutdown/restart because of an update or other reason. I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening while a script is running in the terminal?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using El Capitan (other osx might work too):

1. You can turn off install updates settings in "System Preferences" to prevent auto updates. Go to System Preferences => App Store => click the lock at the lower left of window to make changes => uncheck the "Automatically check for updates" and the boxes below.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ8xA.png)
2. Go to System Preferences => Energy Saver and click "Schedule" at lower right of window. Check to see if you have set a auto-shutdown time for your Mac. If so, disable it to prevent Mac from shutting down by itself. If it's not the case, don't change any settings.

Hope this helps! P.S. my first Stack Overflow answer!

Comment: Thanks. I did that. We'll see if it helps in the future